# How to bypass screen/byobu conflicts with zssh file transfers (rz/sz)

Tags: gnu-screen, tty, pty, byobu

I've been trying out [zssh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/zssh.1.html)'s `sz` and `rz` because it seems like a quick/easy way to send files back and forth (local <-> remote) over `ssh`. The problem is that I use `byobu` (basically `screen`) on my remote server and this somehow conflicts with the sending and receiving of files.

http://zssh.sourceforge.net/FAQ

Number 6 states that:

```
Beware that any program interferring (ie non transparent) with the tty/pty
chain will likely prevent file tranfers from working.

For example, running 'screen' on the REMOTE side will prevent zssh from
working properly because it will be messing things between rz and sz.
```

This is a total bummer because running `byobu` is an essential part of my remote management toolkit and I haven't found any tool that seems as effortless as `zssh`.

Can anyone think of a way to get `zssh` working without having to disable `byobu/screen`? I would troubleshoot it myself, but this sort of stuff is way over my head (as in, I have no clue why `screen` would even conflict with a file transmission process like this, so an explanation would be extremely helpful).

Also, any alternative solutions to this problem would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Wondering if there's a way to quickly drop out of `byobu`, perform `zssh` tasks then jump back into the previous `byobu` session...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boom. Got it:

On local, `zssh me@remote.com -p <your port>`

On remote `byobu` you'll want to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to detach your session for a moment (don't worry, we'll get it back after this transfer).

Now that we're in a plain old shell on the remote server, let's send a file from your local machine to the remote machine. On the remote, type: `rz` to get ready to receive in this directory (`pwd`).

Now, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the `zssh` prompt (this prompt is essentially using your local machine's terminal now). Find the file you want (e.g. `BillLumberg.gif`) and type:

`sz BillLumberg.gif`

The file will automagically send itself to the remote machine and bring you back to the remote prompt.

Now that the file is uploaded, let's jump back to your previous `byobu` session.

`byobu -list` will show you all of the existing `byobu` sessions:

```
There is a screen on:
    8515.byobu  (10/21/2012 12:36:23 PM)    (Detached)
```

to restore the specific session, type: `byobu -r 8515` and voila. All you actually have to do is `byobu -R` to restore the previously used session.

**TLDR:**

1. `zssh me@remote.com -p <port>`
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to detach current `byobu`
3. `rz` to enter receive mode (step only necessary for remote -> local)
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to local `zssh` prompt
5. `sz <filename>` to send file
6. `byobu -R` to restore previous session

just swap steps 3 and 5 to send a file from remote to local!

Comment: of course, this is just a workaround. would love to not have to leave byobu to run this tool!